# How to embed a c# app to SP website without Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an app in c# that does the following

-- Connects to a local intranet database and executes `select` queries

--Post the results of these queries on Sharepoint website

--Sends emails with the results

--Does this on a scheduled basis (as user sets up )

I wanted to embed this app into the SharePoint website. However, I do not have SP Server on my computer and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`

Is there any way I could still embed this app into the SP website using `SP Web Services` or any other way ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *`embed this app into the SP website `*

Comment: The app has a GUI window and users can create new reports, schedule them , and track them. I want this application be an applet that would be a `web part` on the website's page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the solution and get the dll.  Then deploy the dll to the SP application pool area or GAC on the SP server. Now connect to the Sharepoint server from your dev machine with 'Sharepoint Designer', and add the  dll in a page layout and reference it. Example of code below

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="CustomCode" Namespace="TYPE HERE" Assembly="TYPE HERE, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=TYPE HERE" %>

<CustomCode:ClassName runat="server"id="Custom" />
```